# Where do these convergence conditions come from?

Tags: probability, stochastic-approximation

I have been reading a [book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf) on Reinforcement Learning and the author mentions "a well-known result in stochastic approximation theory" that gives us the conditions required to assure convergence in probability 1. Screenshot of these conditions below:

[image]

What is this well-known result? I've been trying to google around for it but am having trouble finding it.

$\ $

**Edit for additional clarity**

Here the $\alpha_n$ are step size parameters for processing rewards. You can see them being defined on p.25 (as it appears on the book page not page count in a PDF reader) of the book, with the below screenshot taken from p.26.

Comment: How can we locate the appropriate portions of the huge book to find the definitions of  $\alpha_n(a)$? By no means are these standard notations.

Answer (score 0):

In a [lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0g4j2k_Ggc4) from David Silver, he mentions that these are the conditions for the [Robbins-Monro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation#Robbins%E2%80%93Monro_algorithm) algorithm to converge, which is what I was looking for.